# HTML PHP Image URL Call

Tags: php, html, image, imgur

I have an image URL, for example, `http://URL/123.jpg`. I can view the image in the browser, but it's not working when using the `<img>` tag in PHP. It's not working, and the idea is somehow not displayed.

```php
echo "<img src=\"http://URL/123.jpg\" style=\"width:11%;height:auto;margin-left: 570px;margin-top: 170px;\">";
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you see the output in the browser console? Add it here so we can see.

Comment: Clearly the issue is related to escaping, Try this echo "<img src='http://test.com/123.jpg' style='width:11%;height:auto;margin-left: 570px;margin-top: 170px;'>";

Comment: @Lucas, the output is blank similar to broken image

Comment: @Vishal based on your answer I'm receiving HTTP ERROR 500, please advise?

Comment: There is an php error, Add this line on top of the page error_reporting(-1); to know the exact error.

Comment: @Vishal PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in. This is the error message. Also I have noticed that if I'm using url like this src="123.jpg" it's working, but my concern is I'm getting the jpg from another web site, so I have to use a url with http. Please advise?

Comment: @user2516703 Can you post whole line which you are using currently?

Comment: If your site is HTTPS, and you're using an image from a HTTP site, it's not going to work. (This is a separate issue from your parse errors, though.)

Comment: @Vishal here is my entire line echo "<img src=\"http://test.com/123.jpg\" style=\"width:11%;height:auto;margin-left: 570px;margin-top: 170px;\">"; I think error in the \"http://test.com/123.jpg\" somewhere because if I called localhost jpg file for example like this \"123.jpg"\ it's working perfectly.

Comment: @ceejayoz. Perfect. The correct answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

For php I use '' and for html the "" quotation marks.
Don't know if it's gonna solve your issue tho. Maybe the `height:auto;` is the problem. I think you can even delete it, if you set the width the height should be auto by default.

```
echo '<img src="http://test.com/123.jpg" style="width:11%;margin-left: 570px;margin-top: 170px;" />';
```

Comment: It's not working, still I can't see the image, please help

Answer (score -2):

Use Normal HTML syntax, include your php then save file as .php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.GONAZbNLqDhBj8q4CpTnCQHaLH%26pid%3DApi&f=1" style="width:100px;height:auto;margin-left: 570px;margin-top: 170px;"/>

<!--your php file-->
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget you have to save this file as PHP.

Comment: No. No no no no no. Don't do this.

Comment: Why? Or if you had the better solution, please SHARE.

Comment: If you read the comments on the question, I did, and OP confirmed it solved their issue.